# c# .net Sandbar.dll

Tags: c#, .net

I am using sandbar.dll version 1.1.0.2 for toolbar menu in wondows application.Its running fine in windows xp,and also run fine if i use classic theme in vista But if i use vista theme it gives blank pop up in vista.

Thx in advance

Comment: Could you please provide less detail?

Comment: Yes more detail please.  For instance can you give us the version number of sandbar?

Comment: lol, I was going to answer "any time" but i like Sean's comment better!

Comment: Which version do you have? Is it the latest one - 1.4.3?

Comment: Mocrisift Wondows Vosta!

Comment: So anyway, I told her to get lost. She's all "but I love you!" and I'm all "whatever". So yeah, all in all pretty awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update your SandBar.dll to the latest version.